# Crystal Report formula to get the grade of student

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to show the grade of a student by calculating the total marks obtained and total maximum marks.
I write the formula given below:

```
local stringVar div := "";
local numberVar num := (ToNumber({StudentResult.S1To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S2To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S3To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S4To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S5To}))*100/
(ToNumber({StudentResult.S1M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S2M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S3M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S4M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S5M}))
If num < 33 Then
(
   div := "FAILED";
)
Else If num >= 33 And num < 45 Then
(
   div := "THIRD";
)
Else If num >= 45 And num < 60 Then
(
   div := "SECOND";
)
Else
(
   div := "FIRST";
);
```

this code is getting error in the if else part. Please if any one knows, help me where I am making mistake to write code. Thanks

Comment: missing `;` at the end of formula `num` formula and then write `if else`

Comment: Thanks Siva, oh I just missed a semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local stringVar div := "";
local numberVar num := (ToNumber({StudentResult.S1To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S2To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S3To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S4To})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S5To}))*100/
(ToNumber({StudentResult.S1M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S2M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S3M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S4M})+ToNumber({StudentResult.S5M}));

If num < 33 Then
(
   div := "FAILED";
)
Else If num >= 33 And num < 45 Then
(
   div := "THIRD";
)
Else If num >= 45 And num < 60 Then
(
   div := "SECOND";
)
Else
(
   div := "FIRST";
);
```